# EOFException при передаче объекта

Tags: java

Идея: клиент передаёт серверу строку, сервер её читает и автоматически возвращает клиенту объект Responce.

Проблема: клиент получает объект и тут же бросает `EOFException`, которого, по идее, не должно быть.

Вопрос: чем он вызван?

(Часть кода вырезал, чтобы не забивал место)

Клиент:

```
package localTransfer;

// imports
public class clientW extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;
private JTextField textField;
private static JTextPane textPane;

static Socket soc = null;
static ObjectInputStream obin = null;
static DataOutputStream dout = null;
static int port = 1255;
static String host = "localhost";

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
    {
        public void run() 
        {
            try 
            {
                clientW frame = new clientW();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    try
    {
        try
        {
            soc = new Socket(host, port);
            dout = new DataOutputStream(soc.getOutputStream());
            obin = new ObjectInputStream(soc.getInputStream());
            while(true)
            {
                Responce res = (Responce) obin.readObject();
                textPane.setText(textPane.getText().trim() + "\n" + res.combineText());
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }           
    finally
    {
        soc.close();
        obin.close();
        dout.close();
    }
}

public clientW() 
{
    // window stuff

    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("send");
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
        {
            try
            {
                dout.writeUTF(textField.getText().trim());
                dout.flush();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    btnNewButton.setBounds(335, 227, 89, 23);
    contentPane.add(btnNewButton);

    // more window stuff
}
}
```

Сервер:

```
package localTransfer;

// imports

public class serverWindow extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;
private static JTextField tfAddition;
static JTextPane tp;

// connection stuff
static ServerSocket ss = null;
static Socket soc = null;
static DataInputStream din;
static ObjectOutputStream obout;
static int port = 1255;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
    {
        public void run() 
        {
            try 
            {
                serverWindow frame = new serverWindow();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    try
    {
        ss = new ServerSocket(port);    
        while(true)
        {
            soc = ss.accept();              
            System.out.println("accepted");
            echoThread X = new echoThread(soc, tp);
            X.start();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        soc.close();
        ss.close();
    }
}

public serverWindow() {
    // window stuff
}
}
```

Отдельный thread для каждого клиента:

```
package localTransfer;

//imports

public class echoThread extends Thread
{
protected Socket soc;
public JTextPane tp;

public echoThread(Socket soc, JTextPane tp)
{
    this.soc = soc;
    this.tp = tp;
}

public void run()
{
    try
    {
        DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(soc.getInputStream());
        while(true)
        {
            try
            {
                String message = din.readUTF();                         
                tp.setText(tp.getText().trim() + "\n" + message);   
                Responce res = new Responce(message, message.length());
                ObjectOutputStream obout = new ObjectOutputStream(soc.getOutputStream());
                obout.writeObject(res);
                obout.flush();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                return;
            }
            finally
            {
                soc.close();
                din.close();
            } 
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял ваш код, сервер получает строку, пишет в сокет в ответ `Responce` и закрывает сокет.

```
soc.close();
```

Клиент же отправляет строку и в цикле бесконечно читает `Responce`

```
while(true){
    Responce res = (Responce) obin.readObject();
     textPane.setText(textPane.getText().trim() + "\n" + res.combineText());
}
```

Но после первого полученного ответа соединение будет разорвано сервером.

Comment: Да. После этого всплыла проблема из-за того, что echoThread закрывал потоки, но её решил сам (сделал стаческими и вынес объявление раньше). Теперь бы решить проблему с несколькими клиентами, чтобы он возвращал ответ тому клиенту, который ему написал, а не последнему из списка. Но это, наверно, в другой вопрос.